# Need to encrypt database password in property file in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, password-encryption

I need to encrypt database password in property file in spring boot application tried using Jasypt, but there are many issues with that. Database used is postgresql.
So looking for alternative way.

Comment: First thing first, why would you like manipulate a property file which is meant to keep static configuration for the different env's of an app?

Comment: please share the code you are facing issues with

Comment: for that you can use jasypt http://www.jasypt.org/ or use a vault for that

Comment: Hi all, Devilluminati I have tired org.jasypt but cant find proper tutorial to follow up.
       Vaibs we have property file the project itself hence it needs to be encrypted.
       @AshishShetkar i have added jasypt:encryptor:password:MY_SECRET in yml file & EnableEncryptableProperties in main application file.
Need some way to encrypt the password in the file, its fine even if the salt key is in the property itself.
Suggest any way if available